# How to deal with a redirect in Microsoft Teams Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams, saml-2.0

I have a simple MS Teams app which just shows my SPA in a personal tab. The app uses SAML-based SSO and of course it requires to make a redirect to an IdP. This redirect happens in my Chrome browser instead of MS Teams tab.

I am wondering if there is any way of forcing MS Teams to use the same tab/iframe to perform redirect? OS: Windows 10.

Small note: if I open my tab in mobile MS Teams app (Android), redirects happen within the app and everything works as expected and user can be successfully authenticated.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots related to the issue you are facing and repro steps 
(how you are doing it right now)?

Giving few reference that might help: Have a look at [Single sign-on support for tabs - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso#apps-that-require-additional-graph-scopes) and [Teams SSO sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp)

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT isn't it not clear from a description? I have an existing app, i use SAML to do SSO, i.e. I have a button in the app saying "Login with SSO". When I click the button my app makes redirect to the IdP Login URL, and then expect a POST from IdP with SAML payload. Now out of curiosity I wanted to see if I can open this app in a personal tab in Teams. Everything seems to be working except for SSO because of redirect. This article doesn't help because it doesn't describe the SSO with SAML.

Comment: Could you please let us know how you are triggering the Auth flow. So that it would be helpful for us to repro the issue. Usually for SSO, Microsoft SDK opens in teams iframe.

Comment: Normal web saml cannot work by definition in an iframe. Your app/tab is in an iframe therfore it will not work. Ever. Unless you follow the above links and advice

Comment: @AndreyStukalin - Could you please let us know if you are still facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Normal web SAML cannot work by definition in an iframe in Teams tab, it has to follow Teams tab supported auth as of now. Giving few reference that might help: Have a look at [Single sign-on support for tabs - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso#apps-that-require-additional-graph-scopes) and [Teams SSO sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp)