# login.microsoftonline.com failing to embed in MS teams

Tags: tabs, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, x-frame-options

We have an web app that we add MS Teams as a tab. It uses AAD for logging in and the SAML2.0 protocol. When setting it up within our own company, it worked without a hitch, but when we tried to add it to the ecosystem of one of our clients, it fails during the login redirect with: "login.microsoftonline.com not allowed to be embedded". We believe the issue is coming from the X-FRAME-Options: DENY

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwL8E.png)

But it's working within our own ecosystem. I asked our client if they have any kind of custom safe-guards in place that might be driving this behaviour but the answer came back negative. Does anyone know where this option could be added in/ removed from? Browsing the net says that that's not something that can be removed, but it definitely is not present in our own setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have followed all the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements)?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT thanks for your reply. Yes, all of those are being set. Our application embeds properly. We can set it to "guest mode" where authentication isn't required and it works fine embedded in teams. It's during authentication, when as part of the flow it redirects to login.microsoftonline.com that the process gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Normal web SAML cannot work by definition in an iframe in Teams tab, it has to follow Teams tab supported auth as of now. Giving few reference that might help: Have a look at [Single sign-on support for tabs - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) and [Teams SSO sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp).

Please refer this question for discussion - [How to deal with a redirect in Microsoft Teams Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404461/how-to-deal-with-a-redirect-in-microsoft-teams-tab)

Comment: But it is working in our own environment. To give more context: we use Keycloak as our SP. It hooks up with AAD through SAML 2.0. Going to our application it redirects it to keycloak which redirects it to login.microsoftonline.com which picks up that the user is logged in and redirects back. Nothing gets blocked. Now the exact same thing on our client's system, it fails during the first redirect between Keycloak and AAD. We haven't written any custom code it's literally config between Keycloak and AAD.

Comment: Can you share the documentation you have followed?